# What connector type is this 3-pin connector from an HP printer power adapter?

Tags: connector

I have this HP 0950-4404 AC Power Adapter, from a discarded printer, that I want to re-purpose. I'd rather keep the connector intact and buy a jack that it fits. I can't find anything online about it. It looks like a Molex connector of some kind with the usual pins and sockets. Does anyone know what this is?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[7 http://s1.postimg.org/475a7x8kt/IMG_2471_cr_rotated_annotated_2.jpg](http://s1.postimg.org/475a7x8kt/IMG_2471_cr_rotated_annotated_2.jpg)

Comment: Can you photo alongside a ruler, so we can see the distance between the pins? It does look similar to molex with a key on one of the pins, but without dimensions its hard to judge.

Comment: The pins are 3/16" on center.

Comment: Looks like a mini-fit of some sort.

Comment: What exactly is a 'mini-fit of some sort'? Do you have a part number for that? :)

Comment: @hmj6jmh Google is your friend. :) http://www.molex.com/product/power/mf.html seems promising. (Took googling for "minifit part connector" to find as the top hit.)

Comment: Saying "Google is your friend" is not at all helpful. Considering I stated in the OP "I can't find anything online about it," it's actually rather insulting. That said, I wasn't really serious when I asked what it was because I thought it quite vague. It was in all lower-case and didn't look like any name of a product line. Now if he had said 'Molex Mini-Fit®', indicating that it WAS a product line, then I would have taken it more seriously and would have at least been inclined to 'Google' it. In any case that was a good stab at it but I found nothing similar on their website.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I contacted Molex and I found out that this is a Molex Mini Fit 3-pin connector custom-made part because the polarization is different from the standard Mini Fits. I asked which part number most closely resembled this one and was told [Part Number: 39-01-4032](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0039014032_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml), **Mini-Fit Jr.™ Plug Housing, Single Row with Panel Mount Ears**

[image: 8]

I ordered some samples and this fits amazingly well. It has 2 square holes but they fit the mating 'pins' well. I had to cut in a groove to accomodate the key and I had to file down the lock tab so it could be disassembled without having to use a finger to lift the tab. So I have all the functionality of the original connector.

[image: 9]
[image: 10]

So it looks like `alex.forencich` and `Michael Kjörling` were right about the general type of connector. Thank you.

Comment: Um, it seems they are similar, but not same exactly.

Comment: What, you were expecting an off-the-shelf component to be **exactly** the same as a custom-made part?! What planet do you live on? ;) I'm really thrilled that they are so similar and are exactly the same in functionality. I really didn't want to have to cut those nice sturdy wires…

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's a female and a male, i didn't notice that :).

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be clear from the images that it was the original male socket mated to the newly acquired female one. As you can see, it fits so well, you thought it was just one connector. :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be an AMP CPS-3.  Notice the bevel exists on all three pin channels, rather than just one like on the Molex.